# In prestashop How to hide a particular hook module only for logged in users

Tags: prestashop-1.5

In my prestashop site i have a banner image for advertising which displays in left side bar for all my inner pages.Now i need to hide the banner section only for logged in users.How to do it?

```
<div class="col-left sidebar">
                {$HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN}
                     {$dedalx.beauty_left_sidebar_customhtml|html_entity_decode}

</div>
```

This is the code used to display the banner image.

Answer (score 0):

```
{if !$logged}
{$htmlboxbody}
{/if}
```

ref [here](http://mypresta.eu/en/art/developer/customer-login-block-hide-after-login.html) and [here](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/290161-solved-hide-hook-extra-left-on-product-page/)

Comment: {$HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN}
{if $logged}
{$dedalx.beauty_left_sidebar_customhtml|html_entity_decode}
{/if}
thats will appear when user login